# VBA Msgbox if cell value is false on worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code it works fine but I only have 1 problem.

it doesn't work way I would like it to.

I want it to Pop up msgbox every time I change the change.

if cell `E45` value is not `"True"` then when I change to different sheet I want it prompt me msg saying `"Records DO NOT Match, would you still like to continue?"`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("E45") <> "TRUE" Then
        MsgBox "Records Do Not Match"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change two things:

First, you need to be using the [**`Workbook_SheetActivate` event**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195710.aspx) to capture when you have selected a different sheet. Next, you should be comparing to the literal `True` value, not the string `"TRUE"`:

The following code should go in the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Range("E45") <> True Then
        MsgBox "Records do not match"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: how about others sheets where I don't want to check?

Answer (score 2):

Amend "TRUE" to TRUE so that it checks for the boolean, not the string "true"

Comment: Problem it, if I make it false it will pop error when I am on current sheet, if I change to different sheet and comeback to it and change sheets again it doesn't pop up error.

Comment: the event is 'on change' so it will only pop up when first changed - do you need it to evaluate on sheet movement too?

Comment: I only want it to run on 4 sheets and not on rest.